# span click add display and hide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a span which acts like a button to display divs depending on what span you click. Each span has its on div containing its content which is displayed none when onload. The problem is that the span when click doesn't do anything. It should be displaying its content.

HTML

```
<p class="lead"><span class="productbtn btn1">FRESH</span><span class="productbtn btn2">CHILLED</span><span class="productbtn btn3">FROZEN</span><span class="productbtn btn4">DRY</span></p>

<div class="section-1" style="display:none">
ASDQWEXZC
</div>

<div class="section-2"  style="display:none">
1234567896
</div>

<div class="section-3"  style="display:none">
1234567896
</div>

<div class="section-4"  style="display:none">
1234567896
</div><p class="lead"><span class="productbtn btn1">FRESH</span><span class="productbtn btn2">CHILLED</span><span class="productbtn btn3">FROZEN</span><span class="productbtn btn4">DRY</span></p>

<div class="section-1" style="display:none">
ASDQWEXZC
</div>

<div class="section-2"  style="display:none">
1234567896
</div>

<div class="section-3"  style="display:none">
1234567896
</div>

<div class="section-4"  style="display:none">
1234567896
</div>
```

CSS

```
.productbtn:hover, productbtn:active {
    background: #bdc3c7;
    color: #fff;
}
.productbtn {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ecf0f1;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s ease all;
}
```

SCRIPT

```
$(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $(".section-1").css("display","block");
    $(".section-2, .section-3, .section-4").css("display","none");
    }); 
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
        $(".section-2").css("display","block");
    $(".section-1, .section-3, .section-4").css("display","none");
    }); 
  $(".btn3").click(function(){
        $(".section-3").css("display","block");
    $(".section-2, .section-1, .section-4").css("display","none");
    }); 
  $(".btn4").click(function(){
        $(".section-4").css("display","block");
    $(".section-2, .section-3, .section-1").css("display","none");
    }); 
});
```

FIDDLE [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelpon12/wy64sdzw/2/)
other Javascript or jquery solutions are acceptable.

FIDDLE [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelpon12/aLkd4545/3/)
For active status resolve the previous issues above.

SCRIPT ACTIVE STATUS:

```
$(function(){
    $(".btn-click").click(function(){
            var active = $(this).addClass("active")
        var target = $(this).data("action");
      $("."+target).show().siblings("div[class*=section-]").hide();
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code wasn't working because you didn't include jQuery. Try adding that in fiddle it will work.

But why to write that long code when you can do it smartly with a much shorter code:

**Here is the jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $(".btn-click").click(function(){
        var target = $(this).data("action");
      $("."+target).show().siblings("div[class*=section-]").hide();
  })
});
```

**Yea that's it, but, if the HTML is like:**

```
<p class="lead"><span class="productbtn btn1 btn-click" data-action="section-1">FRESH</span><span class="productbtn btn2 btn-click" data-action="section-2">CHILLED</span><span class="productbtn btn3 btn-click" data-action="section-3">FROZEN</span><span class="productbtn btn4 btn-click" data-action="section-4">DRY</span></p>

<div class="section-1" style="display:none">
ASDQWEXZC
</div>

<div class="section-2"  style="display:none">
1234567896
</div>

<div class="section-3"  style="display:none">
1234567896
</div>

<div class="section-4"  style="display:none">
1234567896
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. great method

Comment: ! more thing sir. I want to add active states to the button. though how do I remove the active class when clicking on other buttons? Check updated fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like you included jQuery

I added it in the external resources section on the left hand, and now it works https://jsfiddle.net/aLkd4545/1/

Here's how to include it in your code(html):

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```